# Circle-circle collision, linear and angular momenta transfer, python

Tags: python, simulation, physics, collision

I am trying to simulate particle collisions in two dimensions. I have found the formulas I need for the transfer of linear momentum. However, I kind of suspect that angular momentum of individual particles will have to be affected if they collide off-center. This is important in my case because my circles have contents inside and it looks unnatural when they just all keep floating and bumping into one another with their contents not changing their orientation whatsoever. I asked ChatGPT about this (because my understanding of mechanics is really bad so I'm not sure which forces I'm supposed to consider and how), but considering my poor knowledge of classical mechanics, I'm not sure I'm getting the right answers from it either. Here's what I got:

> The detailed formulas for simulating the collision of two balls with off-center impacts, including the resulting linear and angular motions, can be complex and depend on the specific characteristics of the collision. However, I can provide you with a simplified overview of the principles involved.
>
> #### Angular Motion:
>
> **Conservation of Angular Momentum:**
>
> - Before Collision: I<sub>*1*</sub>*ω<sub>*1i*</sub> + I<sub>*2*</sub>*ω<sub>*2i*</sub> = Total Initial Angular Momentum
> - After Collision: I<sub>*1*</sub>*ω<sub>*1f*</sub> + I<sub>*2*</sub>*ω<sub>*2f*</sub> = Total Final Angular Momentum
>
> **Torque τ During Collision:**
>
> - If the collision is off-center, there will be a torque **τ** acting on the system during the collision.
> - τ = r * F, where **r** is the lever arm (distance from the axis of rotation to the point of application of force) and **F** is the force applied during the collision.
>
> **Angular Impulse α:**
>
> - The torque **τ** is related to the change in angular momentum through the angular impulse.
> - I * α = τ * ∆t, where **I** is the moment of inertia and *α* is the angular acceleration.
> - lever arm **r** is the magnitude of **d⊥**, that is, r = |d⊥|.
> - **d⊥** is calculated as
>   [image], where **d** is the vector connecting the centers of colliding circles and **v<sub>rel</sub>** is their relative velocities.

Are any of these formulas correct?

I am particularly concerned with the vector multiplication in the last formula that I don't quite get.

Comment: You might want to ask this in physics stackexchange.